# changing values in nested json file with a recursive function in Python

Tags: python, json, recursion, nested

Hi I want to create a recursive function that can take a dictionary made out of a nested json file and multiply by 10 all the values of one of the attribute (the attribute weight) in the json file.

I know this can be solved in other ways (regex for example) but I am doing this to improve my ability to write recursive functions, so I want to find a recursive solution.

example input json file :

```
    {
      "name": "Entire genepool",
      "children": [{
        "name": "child1",
        "weight": 80,
        "children": [{
          "name": "childAA",
          "weight": 100,
          "children": [{
            "name": "childCC",
            "weight": 60,
            "children": []
          }, {
            "name": "grandchild",
            "weight": 40,
            "children": []
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "childb",
        "weight": 20,
        "children": []
      }]
    }
```

this what I have done so far (Python 2.7) , it doesn't work, it returns an empty list, I added a print statement to visualize how the input dictionary changes through the recursion:

```
    def recur(dict1):
        print dict1
        print 
        """
        it multiplies * 10 weight attribute in nested json file
        """
        # reduce on step closer to solution
        if not isinstance(dict1, list):
            for key , content in dict1.iteritems():
                if key == "weight":
                    dict1["weight"] = dict1["weight"]*10 
            for key , content in dict1.iteritems():
                if key == "children":
                    simpler_dict = dict1["children"]
                    return  recur(simpler_dict)
        else:
            if len(dict1) < 1:
                return dict1
            else:
                for sub_dict in dict1:
                    for key , content in sub_dict.iteritems():
                        if key == "weight":
                            sub_dict["weight"] = sub_dict["weight"]*10 
                    for key , content in sub_dict.iteritems():
                        if key == "children":
                            simpler_dict2 = sub_dict["children"]
                            return  recur(simpler_dict2)
```

## opening the file converting it to a dictionary and calling the function

```
with open("tree_rec.json", "r") as f:
    tree_dic = json.load(f)
recur(tree_dic)
```

## input of each recursion

```
  {u'name': u'Entire genepool', u'children': [{u'name': u'child1', u'weight': 80, u'children': [{u'name': u'childAA', u'weight': 100, u'children': [{u'name': u'childCC', u'weight': 60, u'children': []}, {u'name': u'grandchild', u'weight': 40, u'children': []}]}]}, {u'name': u'childb', u'weight': 20, u'children': []}]}

  [{u'name': u'child1', u'weight': 80, u'children': [{u'name': u'childAA', u'weight': 100, u'children': [{u'name': u'childCC', u'weight': 60, u'children': []}, {u'name': u'grandchild', u'weight': 40, u'children': []}]}]}, {u'name': u'childb', u'weight': 20, u'children': []}]

  [{u'name': u'childAA', u'weight': 100, u'children': [{u'name': u'childCC', u'weight': 60, u'children': []}, {u'name': u'grandchild', u'weight': 40, u'children': []}]}]

  [{u'name': u'childCC', u'weight': 60, u'children': []}, {u'name': u'grandchild', u'weight': 40, u'children': []}]

  []
```

it returns an empty list: []

Comment: "doesn't work" is the least useful description of a problem. Please explain in which way it "doesn't work" (and if you get an exception, please post the exact error message and the full traceback.

Comment: Oh and yes: you don't even show how you're calling that function...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Add `print` statements to trace your function's execution or run it in the step debugger (https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) and the problem should be very obvious. Hint: write your function so that it either mutates it's input and returns nothing OR  (exclusive "or") create a new (modified) dict and returns it, but don't try to mix both.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the recursion you are looking for can be attained like this:

```
def main_caller(json_file):
    if "weight" in json_file:
        json_file["weight"] *= 10
    if "children" in json_file and json_file["children"]:
        for child_index , children in enumerate(json_file["children"]):
            json_file["children"][child_index] = main_caller(children)
    return json_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to look for 'weight'-keys in the dicts and iterate over all lists, your recur function can be a lot simpler:

```
x =  {"name": "Entire genepool", ...}

def recur(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            if key == 'weight':
              data[key] = value*10
            elif isinstance(value, list):
              for i, item in enumerate(value):
                value[i] = recur(item)
        return data

result = recur(x)
```

Result:

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "children": [
                {
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "children": [],
                            "name": "childCC",
                            "weight": 600
                        },
                        {
                            "children": [],
                            "name": "grandchild",
                            "weight": 400
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "childAA",
                    "weight": 1000
                }
            ],
            "name": "child1",
            "weight": 800
        },
        {
            "children": [],
            "name": "childb",
            "weight": 200
        }
    ],
    "name": "Entire genepool"
}
```